# How can I highlight menu while scrolling the page in blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I wanna highlight the menu while scrolling the page. As we know, there are so many tutorials about this.

For example, here is one by JQUERY: http://suo.im/6q97rQ

Now the problem is it seems the Blazor server-side has forbidden some method of JQUERY that it can not run perfectly.

In the tutorial above, the scroll method never works.

I searched for something about Blazor forbidden JQUERY, most of the solution is to invoke JQUERY by the Blazor code.

However, I don't know how to get the scrolling event by the Blazor code.

Would you please help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

1. You can use `onscroll` for detected **you scroll page change states**. [Event argument types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#event-argument-types)
2. You can call `js` function by using `JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("yourFunction");`